# linq-to-sql getting state of value at a certain date

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a db table that looks like this: State is a number that ranges from 1 to 6 and I'm storing the days on which the state changes.

```
|  State |     Date   |
|    3   |  5/19/2012 |
|    1   |  6/12/2012 |
|    4   |  7/2/2012  |
```

I'm writing a `.Where` clause but I'm stuck. Basically, I'm query data for a certain date and one of the properties of the object model I want is the State on that certain date.
If I write:

```
   from s in MyDC.StateTable
   where s.Date == SomeDate.Date
   select s.State
```

then of course it's not going to return what I need. For instance, if I'm querying for 6/22/2012 then it should return 1 because that's the state for that date; it was set to 1 on 6/12/2012. How do I write this where clause?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like:

```
// var date = DateTime.Now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromMonths(1));
var state = MyDC.StateTable.Where(xx => date >= xx.Date)
                           .OrderBy(xx => xx.Date)
                           .First()
                           .State;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
var date = ??;

var state = from s in MyDC.StateTable
where x.SomeDate.Date ==  date
select s.State;
```

Comment: no, I mean if I'm querying for 6/22/2012 then the state is equal to 1 because that's what it was set to on 6/12/2012.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work. Not sure the syntax is exactly correct, but it's close.

```
var state = MyDC.StateTable
   .Where(row => row.Date <= SomeDate)
   .OrderByDescending(row.Date)
   .First()
   .Select(row => row.State)
```